# How to satisfy 1NF with food ingredients?

Tags: normalization

Take the below table as an example of my situation. How would you organise ingredients so that the values are atomic and satisfy 1NF?

```
Product Code        Manufacturer        Product Name        Product Weight        Ingredients
001                 Safeways            Horse meat          100                   sugar,salt,water,horsemeat
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing a commma separated list of values clearly violates the "atomic" requirement of 1NF.

What you want is a (at least) a 1-to-many relationship. One table to store the product attributes and one table to store the ingredients per product.

- `product (code[PK], manufacturer, name, total_weight)`
- `product_ingredient (product_code, name)`

However this means you can add "Sugar" to one product and "sugar" to another and "SUGAR" to yet another. If your ingredients are always the same across products, then it's better to model this as a many-to-many relationship:

- `product (code[PK], manufacturer, name, weight)`
- `ingredient (code[pk], name)`
- `product_ingredient (product_code, ingredient_code)`

With `product_code` being a foreign key to `product.code` and `ingredient_code` being a foreign key to `ingredient.code`.

If each ingredient can only be used *once* in a product, then `(product_code, ingredient_code)` is the primary key of that relation.

If you want to store how much of each ingredient is used in each product, just extend the `product_ingredient` relation to:

- `product_ingredient (product_code, ingredient_code, weight)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still trying to get my head around it... Why can't I do this: http://s3.postimg.org/61kys1m2b/test.png ?

Comment: @adampski A (comma separated) list of values is not atomic because it *consists* of multiple values and thus isn't atomic which violates 1NF. Instead of storing a list of actual values you are now storing a list of FK values - but that's still a _list_, not a _single_ value

Comment: Gotcha. I've drawn up [this](http://bit.ly/1ffGvj2). I believe the contents box should have been on the right hand side to show it has a 'bridge' table but none the less, I believe my understanding is now there. What do you think? Also, I believe your recommendation for many-to-many is better, for not just preventing the different variations of the string `sugar`, but also so it can prevent `sugar` being entered 50 times for 50 different sugary items. Now there's just 1 ID for `sugar`. Am I on the right lines...?